# what is the kind of return value of boost filesystem size()

Tags: boost, boost-filesystem

In what unit the size of the file is returned in boost filesystem???

that is `boost::filesystem::size()`  returns an int value. whether it is the size of the file in bits or bytes????

please help me in finding this!

Comment: Try to call it on a file of known size!

Comment: By the way, if you mean "boost::filesystem::file_size(const path&)", you can simply check the official documentation. It says explicitly that it is measured in bytes.

Answer (score 0):

`boost::filesystem::size()` returns the size of the file  in "bytes"

Thanks for your comments & helping me in finding this!